# Constant to String in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have the following line of code:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing then
        set trackMediaKind to media kind of current track
        display dialog trackMediaKind
    end if
end tell
```

When I print `trackMediaKind` I get the following: `«constant ****kMdS»`

In iTunes the `media kind` looks like:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/AkMr67J.png]

Is there way to make it print `Music` instead of `«constant ****kMdS»`?

## -Edit-

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing then
        set trackMediaKind to media kind of current track
        log trackMediaKind as string
    end if
end tell
```

I ran the code up via the terminal by typing: `osascript myscript.scpt` it stills returns: `«constant ****kMdS»`.

Comment: Unless one explicitly states the environment one is running code under it logical to assume the default, which in this case would have been Script Editor, before the edit you made after accepting the answer. This is another case why [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be followed when requesting help debugging code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following line of *code* from:

```
display dialog trackMediaKind
```

To:

```
display dialog trackMediaKind as string
```

If you really want it to display "Music" then you need to do something such as:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing then
        set trackMediaKind to media kind of current track
        if trackMediaKind as string is "song" then
            display dialog "Music"
        end if
    end if
end tell
```

BTW In the **AppleScript Dictionary** for **iTunes** (12.7.*) , looking at the *properties* of a `track`, the `media kind` shows:

> **media kind** (alert tone/‌audiobook/‌book/‌home video/‌iTunesU/‌movie/‌song/‌music video/‌podcast/‌ringtone/‌TV show/‌voice memo/‌unknown) : the media kind of the track

In other words, you'll need to test the results against what could be returned and process it accordingly to your needs/wants if you want to display differently the returned. Also, anytime it returns things like e.g. `«constant ****kMdS»` try coercing to text with `as string` or `as text`.

---

**Update to address the after the fact edit to your question:**

While you didn't originally state in the OP you were running your script in **Terminal** using `osascript`, nonetheless there seems to be an issue between running the same code as a `.scpt` file in the two different environments. One would think that what works correctly in **Script Editor**, it would work correctly in **Terminal** using `osascript`, but in this particular case it doesn't.

The workaround in this particular case is to not use the `.scpt` file format and instead use a plain text format:

As an example, the following *code* should display a dialog box with "song" when a song track is playing **iTunes** and saved in **Script Editor** as **Text**, e.g. **myscript.applescript**, and then run in **Terminal** using: `osascript myscript.applescript`

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing then
        set trackMediaKind to media kind of current track
        display dialog trackMediaKind as string
    end if
end tell
```

---

One can also use the **AppleScript** *code* in plain text format and make the file executable to be used directly without having to first type `osascript` on the command line. Save the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* using an `osascript` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing then
        set trackMediaKind to media kind of current track
        display dialog trackMediaKind as string
    end if
end tell
```

Make executable with `chmod` in **Terminal**, e.g.:

```
chmod u+x myscript.applescript
```

Then, if it's in the current directory, execute the script using:

```
./myscript.applescript
```

Otherwise, use the *pathname* to it, if it's not in the `PATH`.

Note: With this method, it is not necessary to use the `.applescript` extension or any extension. It's a users preference, even though **Script Editor** uses that extension by default for plain text **AppleScript** *code* files.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I edited the original question a bit, look at the bottom of the question when I run the script through the terminal I get: `«constant ****kMdS»` coercing doesn't do the trick there.

Comment: @Do0med, I've update my answer to reflect your after the fact edit.